# Why does using Unicode in a properties file work but not the actual character even when file.encoding is set?

Tags: java, unicode, properties-file

Here is the test.properties file.

```
mycharacters=ýþÿƛƸ
myotherchars=\u00FD\u00FE\u00FF\u019B\u01B8
```

Here is the code being used :

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MultiByteTest2 
{
    public MultiByteTest2()
    {
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MultiByte Test");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(bundle.getString("mycharacters"));
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("  ---  " + bundle.getString("myotherchars"));

        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(label2);

        String defaultCharacterEncoding = System.getProperty("file.encoding");
        System.out.println("defaultCharacterEncoding by property: " + defaultCharacterEncoding);
        System.out.println("defaultCharacterEncoding by code: " + getDefaultCharEncoding());
        System.out.println("defaultCharacterEncoding by charSet: " + Charset.defaultCharset());

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void main(String s[]) 
    {
        MultiByteTest2 myObject = new MultiByteTest2();

    }

    public static String getDefaultCharEncoding(){
        byte [] bArray = {'w'};
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bArray);
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
        String defaultCharacterEncoding = reader.getEncoding();
        return defaultCharacterEncoding;
    }

}
```

Here is the output :

[image]

Command to run the above code and the output which shows UTF-8 being used.

```
 >java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 MultiByteTest2
 Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
 defaultCharacterEncoding by property: UTF-8
 defaultCharacterEncoding by code: UTF8
 defaultCharacterEncoding by charSet: UTF-8
```

Three questions :

1. Why does using the actual characters result in a mess of characters being output?
2. Why does using the Unicode representation work?
3. The output shows UTF-8 instead of cp1252 which indicates the file.encoding is being used, but why does it not help when using the actual characters in the properties file?

Comment: The default encoding Java uses would be the system encoding; so your code seems off there (if you want "cp1252" **specify** "cp1252"). Have you tried "UTF-16"?

Comment: The default is cp1252. The output showing UTF-8 is to confirm that the file.encoding parameter is being passed in successfully. Using UTF-16 results in the same output as using UTF-8 or cp1252.

Answer (score 3):

*.properties use ISO-8859-1, Latin-1. This is a very old design decision. By u-escaping Unicode can be read.

I think the cleanest solution would be to use the [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML(java.io.InputStream)) class, and maybe XML properties (`loadFromXML`). The XML could also be held outside the application, which for internationalisation can be a usefull.

One could also in a maven build convert pre-build *.properties in UTF-8 to u-escaped *.properties. This is a maven copy with filtering.

---

Instead of *.properties, a PropertyResourceBundle, you could also use a ListResourceBundle, a java class containing an array of texts. The resource path in ResBundle can be slightly different w.r.t. period/slash, but that would free
one from the encoding, as you can use the IDE project encoding.

Comment: I thought the "file.encoding" option is supposed to override what the *.properties uses.

Comment: @UnhandledException No, the way you use `ResourceBundle` will ultimately use [`new PropertyResourceBundle(InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html#PropertyResourceBundle-java.io.InputStream-) which will use [`Properties.load(InputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.InputStream-) which by specification **always** uses ISO-8859-1. This is something that is specified repeatedly in the javadoc.

Comment: It is one of the dumbest specifications-after-implementation, but at that time UTF-8 was still not that ubiquitous.

Comment: I read a number of threads/posts about using file.encoding and how it is the answer to this question, but not one that I found discussed the restriction how it applies the the PropertyResourceBundle. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @UnhandledException `file.encoding` is applied by things like `FileReader` and `new String(byte[])` and `InputStreamReader` when you don't specify an explicit character. As far as I know it was an intentional design decision to not do this with `.properties` to avoid deployment issues (eg deploy an application in a region with default Cp1250 instead of Cp1252 and suddenly the resources are garbage). So contrary to Joop's assertion it is a 'specification-after-implementation', I think it is intentional design.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you are right, that resource files should have a fixed encoding and not differ on every platform. It is really a cumbersome solution nowadays. If they would have allowed only US-ASCII, there would be no source of mistakes, as shown in the question. But the JDK developers just wanted to ease of some Latin-1 languages. Maybe I am wrong and it passed a specification review, but a properties files suggests human processable text without really being it.